# How do I write an exit handler for an F# application?

Tags: .net, f#, exit-handler

Subject says it all.

I want some code to run if my application is terminated by, say, ^C.

Comment: Just a thought--although you're asking about F# you could probably google for ".Net Application Termination Event" and find more information on the general question of how to handle this sort of issue properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AppDomain.ProcessExit` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit.Add(fun _ -> ...)
```

Comment: Maybe ProcessExit (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) will be more suitable for case of normal process termination. In simple console example
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit.Add(fun _ -> printfn "ProcessExit")
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload.Add(fun _ -> printfn "DomainUnload")

it outputs "ProcessExit" after exit.

Comment: Absolutely! How could I miss it?

Answer (score 1):

See code below.  To handle Ctrl-C in a console app, use the [Console.CancelKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx) event.

```
// does not work - no exception on Ctrl-C
//System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.Add(
//    fun _ -> printfn "app is about to die")

System.Console.CancelKeyPress.Add(
    fun _ -> printfn "app is about to die")
printfn "starting..."
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)  // press Ctrl-C
printfn "ended"
```

Comment: Note that this only handles ^C termination, not arbitrary process exit.