# Converting OCaml to F#: F# equivelent of Pervasives at_exit

Tags: events, f#, ocaml

I am converting the OCaml [Format](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) module to F# and tracked a problem back to a use of the OCaml [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) at_exit.

```
val at_exit : (unit -> unit) -> unit
```

**Register the given function to be called at program termination time.** The functions registered with `at_exit` will be called when the program executes exit, or terminates, either normally or because of an uncaught exception. The functions are called in "last in, first out" order: the function most recently added with `at_exit` is called first.

In the process of conversion I commented out the line as the compiler did not flag it as being needed and I was not expecting an event in the code.

I checked the `FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility.PervasivesModule` for `at_exit` using VS Object Browser and found none.

I did find [how to run code "at_exit"?](http://cs.hubfs.net/topic/None/57968) and [How do I write an exit handler for an F# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3368751/1243762)

The OCaml line is

```
at_exit print_flush
```

with print_flush signature:  `val print_flush : (unit -> unit)`

Also in looking at the use of it during a debug session of the OCaml code, it looks like `at_exit` is called both at the end of initialization and at the end of each use of a call to the module.

Any suggestions, hints on how to do this. This will be my first event in F#.

EDIT

Here is some of what I have learned about the Format module that should shed some light on the problem.

The Format module is a library of functions for basic pretty printer commands of simple OCaml values such as int, bool, string. The format module has commands like `print_string`, but also some commands to say put the next line in a bounded box, think new set of left and right margins. So one could write:

```
print_string "Hello"
```

or

```
open_box 0; print_string "<<";
open_box 0; print_string "p \/ q ==> r"; close_box();
print_string ">>"; close_box()
```

The commands such as `open_box` and `print_string` are handled by a loop that interprets the commands and then decides wither to print on the current line or advance to the next line. The commands are held in a queue and there is a state record to hold mutable values such as left and right margin.

The queue and state needs to be primed, which from debugging the test cases against working OCaml code appears to be done at the end of initialization of the module but before the first call is made to any function in the Format module. The queue and state is cleaned up and primed again for the next set of commands by the use of mechanisms for `at_exit` that recognize that the last matching frame for the initial call to the format modules has been removed thus triggering the call to `at_exit` which pushes out any remaining command in the queue and re-initializes the queue and state.

So the sequencing of the calls to `print_flush` is critical and appears to be at more than what the OCaml documentation states.

Comment: You could just put a `finally` inside your main method

Comment: Another idea - hold on to a single instance of a type and then let the destructor get called when the program exits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
module Pervasives =
    open System
    open System.Threading

    //
    let mutable private exitFunctions : (unit -> unit) list = List.empty

    //
    let mutable private exitFunctionsExecutedFlag = 0

    //
    let private tryExecuteExitFunctions _ =
        if Interlocked.CompareExchange (&exitFunctionsExecutedFlag, 1, 0) = 0 then
            // Run the exit functions in last-in-first-out order.
            exitFunctions
            |> List.iter (fun f -> f ())

    // Register handlers for events which fire when the process exits cleanly
    // or due to an exception being thrown.
    do
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit.Add tryExecuteExitFunctions
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.Add tryExecuteExitFunctions

    //
    let at_exit f =
        // TODO : This function should be re-written using atomic operations
        // for thread-safety!
        exitFunctions <- f :: exitFunctions
```

And some code to test it:

```
open System

// Register a couple of handlers to test our code.
Pervasives.at_exit <| fun () ->
    Console.WriteLine "The first registered function has fired!"

Pervasives.at_exit <| fun () ->
    Console.WriteLine "The second registered function has fired!"
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds 1.0
    |> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep
    Console.WriteLine "Exiting the second registered function!"

Pervasives.at_exit <| fun () ->
    Console.WriteLine "The third registered function has fired!"

// Do some stuff in our program
printfn "blah"
printfn "foo"
printfn "bar"

(* The functions we registered with at_exit should be fired here. *)

// Uncomment this to see that our handlers work even when the
// program crashes due to an unhandled exception.
//failwith "Uh oh!"
```